# phmm visualization

Tags: hidden-markov-models, hmmer

I have used HMMER search and I have created a phmm. But I would like to visualize it, not as a logo but as a phmm. I do not have Linux, so I cannot use build hmmer. Is there any web browser that I could use?Thank you!

---

[HMMER](http://hmmer.org) searches databases for protein homologs. This can contribute to making sequence alignments. HMMER uses an advanced statistical approach (profile hidden Markov models).

PHMM is a profile hidden Markov models, i.e. an output of HMMER which would be used to represent a protein family.